# Multiple Table Join in Linq C# Dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 3 data tables: `a`; `b`; and `c`. In this I need to write Join Query Dynamically using **LINQ**.

The Selecting columns given by customer and Condition columns also given customer at run time.

So I need to create queries dynamically. Please check below example. Because I don't know which table they want and which column also

For example

```
Select a.c1,a.c2,b.c1,b.c2 From a Left Join b on a.c1=b.c1

Select c.c1,c.c2,a.c1,a.c2 From c Left Join a on c.c3=a.c1

Select a.c1,a.c2,b.c1,b.c2,c.c1,c.c2 From a Left Join b on a.c2=b.c2 Left join c on c.c1=a.c1
```

Like I need create different set of queries. Please help me on this.

Comment: I can write Static query like below var query = from aa in a
      join bb in b on aa.c1 equals bb.c1
      select new { aa.Name, bb.Product }; But what i want is dynamically writing above query based on table and columns,That only i dont know how to do.please help me.

Comment: @kmkperumal a b and c are horrible examples and make it really hard to read... can't you make an example with real-life names, even if they are silly? See the example with fruit and car by akim.

Comment: How you solved this scenario? Iam facing same situation

Answer (score 3):

You could use either `System.Linq.Dynamic`([ScottGu's blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic)) in case of dynamic where clause:

```
var results = (from fruit in fruits 
    join car in cars on fruit.Id equals car.Id
    select new { fruit, car })
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where("fruit.ColA != car.ColA")
    .Where("fruit.ColB == car.ColB");
```

Or dynamicaly build expressions this using [extensions from `PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) writen by @joe-albahari. For example:

```
var predicate = 
    PredicateBuilder
        .True<Tuple<Product, Product>>()
        .And(t => t.Item1.ColA != t.Item2.ColA)
        .And(t => t.Item1.ColB == t.Item2.ColB)
        .Compile();    

(from fruit in fruits 
    join car in cars on fruit.Id equals car.Id
    select Tuple.Create(fruit, car))
    .Where(predicate)
    .Dump();
```

ps: full code available at [gisthub](https://gist.github.com/4259463)

Comment: This doesn't do a "dynamic join". The fruit.ID equals car.ID is hard coded and cannot be changed during runtime.