# Dynamic linq join extension method usage

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to test out a dynamic join extension method as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389094/how-to-create-a-dynamic-linq-join-extension-method) to join products with categories in the Northwind SQL database. However I'm not 100% familiar with lambda expressions and fail to understand how to make the following SQL query using this extension method

```
select * from dbo.Products p
join dbo.Categories c on c.categoryID = p.CategoryID
where p.CategoryID =3 and UnitPrice > 3
```

Here is my dynamic linq query.

```
var queryProducts = northwind.Products
 .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
 .OrderBy("SupplierID");

var queryCategory = northwind.Categories
  .Where("CategoryID=3")
  .AsEnumerable();

var queryJoin = queryProducts.Join(queryCategory, "CategoryId", "CategoryId", "new(1 as abcd)",null);
```

This fails with exception: "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No method 'Join' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied arguments."

Any ideas on how to modify the Join above to make it work?

Comment: I need to perform the join dynamically and only know which tables/columns to join on at run time, hence the need to use the extension method

Comment: I really can't see how that would work. The processor can't convert strings to table and column names. If there was a column UnitPrice in two of the tables, how would it know which table to check the value in?

Comment: There must be some way to do the above using the extension method with aliases or similar

Comment: It looks like you can dynamically build up the where statement from a string, but I don't think you can name the tables as strings. 
If those three tables were foreign keyed it'd be easier

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918534/multiple-table-join-in-linq-c-sharp-dynamically) names the tables explicitly, then lets you use a string to specify the where clause

Comment: thanks mikey. Now I need to find the Join syntax.